# finding the minimum value of $\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given $f(x)=\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$.

Need to find the min value of $f(x)$.

I know it can be easily done by polynomial division but my question is if there's another way

(more elegant maybe) to find the min?

**About my way**: $f(x)=\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}=x^2-x+1$. (long division)

$x_{min}=\frac{-b}{2a}=\frac{1}{2}$. (when $ax^2+bx+c=0$)

So $f(0.5)=0.5^2-0.5+1=\frac{3}{4}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2-x+1=\frac{4x^2-4x+4}4=\frac{(2x-1)^2+3}4\ge\frac34$$

The equality occurs if $2x-1=0\iff x=\dfrac12$

Comment: very nice! thanks, but still it's from a long division.

Comment: @dave, $$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-(x)^2=\cdots$$

Comment: got it! that's what i was looking for:)

Comment: but in your answer isn't it easier: $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: @dave, I wanted to avoid fractions:)

Comment: @dave In future you should try to title your question better. I read the title and went straight to answer that. But the question of the body was not the question of the title.

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge - i don't think i did something wrong. i didn't tag it in calculus and also in the body i detailed what i was looking for and what i did. but if i didn't follow the rules, im sorry and ill learn next time.

Comment: @dave Don't worry much :). I just mean the title wasn't very good. It says "Finding the minimum value of $\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$" - When it should be something like 'Finding minimum without using long division'

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}=x^2-x+1$$
$$f'(x) = 2x-1=0,x=\frac12$$
$$f''(\frac12)=2\gt0\text{ hence this is a local minimum by the second derivative test}$$

Comment: The post is tagged as algebra-precalculus, so while you are correct I believe that this answer might not be particularly helpful to dave.

Comment: @JRP Fair call. I will wait and see what he has to say, thanks for input.

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge - thanks but i'm looking for a way without the long division:) but i appreciate your answer.

Comment: @dave You have a problem with the long-division, or my derivatives(or both)?

Comment: mostly the long division.

Comment: @Dave is that because it is hard to remember, or you got it in the question body by wolframalpha(or other)? Do you understand the second derivative test and/or setting the first derivative to $0$?

Comment: @because i didn't learn it yet in school so im looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the fraction by $\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-1}$:$$\frac{(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{x^6-1}{(x+1)(x^3-1)}=\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}=x^2-x+1$$